# SQL Query must start from SELECT, it starts FROM WITH - can't make over

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In my CRM system I am able to paste own SQL Queries. Add query form has a limit - it doesn't accept queries not starting from SELECT statement.

I have a query which starts from WITH statement and I have no idea how to change it to start from SELECT statement.

```
;WITH dRange(d) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, Convert(date, getdate()+1), GETDATE()+31)+1) 
        DATEADD(DAY, n-1, Convert(varchar(10), GETDATE()+1,120))
     FROM (SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
      FROM sys.objects) AS x

), possible(ds, de) AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 30*rn, DATEADD(HOUR, 9, dRange.d)),
        DATEADD(MINUTE, 30*rn + 60, DATEADD(HOUR, 9, dRange.d))
    FROM (SELECT TOP (720/30) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (ORDER BY [object_id])-1 FROM sys.objects) AS x
    CROSS JOIN dRange
)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), p.ds, 121) AS 'Start', CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), p.de, 121) AS 'End'
FROM possible AS p 
WHERE p.de <= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, p.de), 0))
```

Maybe it is possible to wrap it inside SELECT statement somehow?

Comment: You might create a VIEW or an (inline) UDF in your SQL Server. This you can call with a `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyNewSource`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an arcane problem but you can structure the query as nested subqueries.  In your case, I think this looks like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), p.ds, 121) AS 'Start', CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), p.de, 121) AS 'End'
FROM (SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 30*rn, DATEADD(HOUR, 9, dRange.d)),
             DATEADD(MINUTE, 30*rn + 60, DATEADD(HOUR, 9, dRange.d))
      FROM (SELECT TOP (720/30) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1 FROM sys.objects
           ) AS x CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, Convert(date, getdate()+1), GETDATE()+31)+1) 
                   DATEADD(DAY, n-1, Convert(varchar(10), GETDATE()+1,120))
            FROM (SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
                  FROM sys.objects
                 ) AS x
           ) dRange
    ) p 
WHERE p.de <= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, p.de), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gordon I find the answer

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), p.ds, 121) AS 'Start', CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), p.de, 121) AS 'End'
FROM (SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 30*rn, DATEADD(HOUR, 9, dRange.d)) as ds,
         DATEADD(MINUTE, 30*rn + 60, DATEADD(HOUR, 9, dRange.d)) as de
  FROM (SELECT TOP (720/30) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1 FROM sys.objects
       ) AS x CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, Convert(date, getdate()+1), GETDATE()+31)+1) 
               DATEADD(DAY, n-1, Convert(varchar(10), GETDATE()+1,120)) as d
        FROM (SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
              FROM sys.objects
             ) AS x
       ) dRange
) AS p
WHERE p.de <= DATEADD(HOUR, 16, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, p.de), 0))
```